# why map.keyset() returns set view but map.values() returns collections in Java?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashmap, keyset

This question is more about design implementation by Java developers. I want to know (if there any vital reason that I cannot think of) why `Keyset()` returns a set-view but `values()` returns `Collection-view`.  why not return `Values()` as a `ValueSet` with `set-view`. I can cast to set if needed, but why it is chosen the way it is.

Maybe this could help in deciding what data structures to use when it comes to building our custom ones.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
map.put("hello",1);
map.put("world",2);

Collection <Integer> i = map.values();
Set<String> s = map.keySet();
```

Comment: Would guess it's because they expect values could be a list or data structure with duplicates in it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By definition the keys of a `Map` form a `Set`, that is a collection of unique keys. The values of a `Map` can be duplicates however. So it is possible to have the same value for different keys in a `Map`.

Comment: Glad to help you friend.